# Travel from Portorož to Budapest

Tags: tips-and-tricks, routes, budapest, slovenia

Can you suggest me the best possible (in terms of cost for 1 person, travel time and comfort during journey) ways for traveling from Portorož to Budapest.
I am tourist, I'll be carrying luggage and I do not want to take flights.
I would like to leave Portorož on 26th May 2016 evening (after 6pm)
and reach Budapest on 27th May 2016 morning/afternoon.

TIA :)

Comment: "Best" is a completely a matter of personal preferences. Some people might prefer to pay more for a more comfortable journey; some people might not.

Comment: I doubt travel agents would suggest a ride share and this corner of the world due to the sub par quality of train tracks and slow buses it's your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bus from Trieste (you can take the ferry there, half an hour) takes nine hours. The train or the bus from Ljubljana takes eight hours -- and you need to get there first which takes two hours on the bus. So far everything takes ten hours. The only way to save time is to get to Ljubljana but from there take a car share. You'll have tons of options because everyone driving from Italy to Hungary these days will go through Slovenia / Ljubljana. Instead of eight hours the Ljubljana-Budapest section will take only five, a grand total of seven hours. Given the drive from Portoroz to Budapest alone takes about six hours it'd be hard to find a quicker option. It is also cheap.

And, whatever "best" means for you, I am unaware of any other even remotely sane options. Flying from Trieste is out because you'd need to connect and thus doesn't save much time. Same for Ljubljana.

This answer is correct as of May 6, 2015 but the train line is part of an EU corridor so it will get faster later. The Hodoš-Pragersko section was just rebuilt up to 160 km/h but that's a short part of the long train ride. Here's a 2016 March 8 [report](http://www.di.gov.si/en/medijsko_sredisce/news/article/1328/5733/8e532cea3ff594bb9604b7cb81e65714/) from the Slovenian government on these matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Can you suggest where I can look for car-share options online ?
I've checked BlaBlaCar and GoOpti already.

Comment: Try http://www.motar.eu/  -- I checked BlaBlaCar myself and there were plenty of options.